# Is there any way to move a file from server to local directory using?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, xul

I search web for a function/command in php/javascript/xul which can transfer a file to local directory from a http server, but didn't find any sufficient answers.

Is there any function/command avaliable to do this job, using any of PHP/Javascript/XUL?

Comment: you can read server file and then write it to the local directory

Comment: ftp/cpanel ?? what exactly ur looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I need to do it by script, not through ftp/cpanel. There will be a fix path in php program to save file on local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the php script for file download:

```
    if (file_exists($file))
    {
        if (FALSE!== ($handler = fopen($file, 'r')))
        {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: chunked'); 
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Pragma: public');       
            //Send the content in chunks
            while(false !== ($chunk = fread($handler,4096)))
            {
                echo $chunk;
            }
        }
        exit;
    }
    echo "<h1>Content error</h1><p>The file does not exist!</p>";
```

Comment: Is there any way by which I can fix the save file path, and file download silently??

Comment: Its upto your browser settings.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php, here is a good example http://www.php.net/manual/en/ftp.examples-basic.php

Try this function http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done with javascript, but in PHP you have to send the proper headers and then serve the file like this:

Example: Force download of CSV file

```
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.csv');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
readfile("/path/to/yourfile.csv");
```